# Decrypting strings C and D without knowing the keys

Tags: encryption, aes

I have a question:

Let’s assume I encrypt string `A` with string key `B`, `C = AES(B,A)` and then I encrypt string `B` with string key `A`,  `D = AES(A,B)`.
Let’s say using AES algorithm.

If an attacker knows that AES is the algorithm I used and also has `C` and `D`, can they figure out strings A and B?

Comment: I think your question is better suited for https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please do not cross-post. Let the communities migrate when necessary.

Comment: You should also say which mode of encryption. Also the length of the 'A' and 'B'. Is padding requires? if lengths are greater than 128 how you convert the string into keys? What is the aim here? Is this kind of **homework**? AES is known to be secure against KPA attack what you are trying to is a variant of CPA attack.